# Installing Universal USB Installer on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb

I want to uninstall `Ubuntu 12.04` and install `Ubuntu 13.4` instead. When I was installing Ubuntu 12.04 from Windows 7 I used **Universal USB Installer** to put `.iso` installer into my USB. Now on Ubuntu 12.04 I can't install **Universal USB Installer**(it gives me an error).

> So how can I install **Universal USB Installer** on Ubuntu 12.04?

Thanks.

Comment: after installing ubuntu this becomes slow and can not move the cursor or open anything, and probe with both versions 32 and 64, but always the same, starts moving fast the pointer, and then gets very lento.yo change USB windows8.1 by ubuntu14.04

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Universal USB Installer is a windows-only program. For Ubuntu you should follow this simple guide to create a bootable USB-Stick:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu